# R dlnm: Cross-basis transformation and distributed lag non-linear models, how to get the coefficient back in the original scale?

Tags: r, transform, lag, coefficients

I am estimating a distributed lag non-linear model thanks to the R package `dlnm`. The independent variable is household consumption at time t, the independent variable is the weather conditions at time t-1 to t-L. The first step consists in using the matrix of weather exposure history to construct a cross-basis matrix where both the exposure and time dimensions can be modeled flexibly (`crossbasis()`). This cross-basis is plugged into a ols regression estimated with `lm()`. The dlnm package provides a few functions to plot and summarize the results (`crosspred()` and `crossreduce()`).

How do we get the parameters in the “original” scale, i.e. before the cross-basis transformation?

I found ways of doing it for a few specifications (see below), but is there a general method?

In the example below, the exposure dimension is modeled as a polynomial of degree 2 and the time dimension as a linear function.

```
library(dlnm)
cb <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp,lag=30,
         argvar=list("poly",degree=2),
         arglag=list("lin"))
model <- lm(cvd~cb,chicagoNMMAPS)
pred <- crosspred(cb,model,at=-20:30)

plot(pred,"slices",lag=0)

# my dirty way:
LAG<-0
SCALE<-attributes(cb)$argvar$scale
ce<-attributes(cb)$argvar$cen

B1<-(summary(model)$coeff[2,1]+summary(model)$coeff[4,1]*LAG)/SCALE
B2<-(summary(model)$coeff[3,1]+summary(model)$coeff[5,1]*LAG)/(SCALE^2)
B0<--(ce*B1+(ce^2)*B2)

xx<-(-20:30)
xx2<-xx^2
yhat<-B0+B1*xx+B2*xx2
lines(-20:30,yhat,lty=2,col="blue")
```

As shown on the graph below, the B's are correct (the blue-dotted line is perfectly aligned with the red line produced via the `dlnm` package). I found my “dirty way” after a lot of wrangling, not much mathematical sense behind it..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8q77.jpg)

Is their a way to get the B's more directly and for all types of functional forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the scale parameter in the `argvar` function to 1. The `crossreduce` function then gives the parameters in the original scale. Below a an example:

```
# with a poly of degree 2 with natural splines at knots 3 and 10
library(dlnm)
cb <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp,lag=30,
             argvar=list("poly",degree=2,scale=1),
             arglag=list("ns",knots=c(3,10)))
model <- lm(cvd~cb,chicagoNMMAPS)
pred <- crosspred(cb,model,at=-20:30)
plot(pred,"slices",lag=3)
ce<-attributes(cb)$argvar$cen

xx<-(-20:30)
xx2<-xx^2
redvar<-crossreduce(cb, model,type="lag",value=3)
b1<-redvar$coefficients[1]
b2<-redvar$coefficients[2]
b0<--(ce*b1+(ce^2)*b2)

yhat<-b0+b1*xx+b2*xx2
lines(-20:30,yhat2,lty=2,col="green")
```